# RCurl getting through proxy (curl works)

Tags: r

I'm having no joy getting through the corporate web proxy with RCurl.

I'm using R 3.1.2 and RCurl 1.95.4.5 on Windows 7.  I've researched the existing stackoverflow workarounds but none of them work.

Here is my code which I expect to work :

```
curl <- getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(.opts = list(proxy = 'proxyIP:proxyPort',
                        proxyuserpwd = "domain\\username:password", 
                        proxyauth="ntlm" 
                       ), curl = curl)

Res <- getURL('http://yahoo.com', curl=curl)
```

After hitting this wall I tried with Curl to diagnose more.  I actually got the request working with Curl using this:

```
curl -x proxyIP:port --proxy-ntlm -U domain\username:password http://yahoo.com
```

I verified with curl (using -v) that NTLM was being used to authenticate.

I don't understand why the RCurl options aren't working as I'm sure I've used the correct setting names.

The error message I see in R is a 407 Proxy Authenticate page.

Is this an RCurl bug?

Answer (score 2):

I sorted it.  With the last throw of the dice :

From :

```
curlSetOpt(.opts = list(proxy = 'proxyIP:proxyPort',
                        proxyuserpwd = "domain\\username:password", 
                        proxyauth="ntlm" 
                       ), curl = curl)
```

To

```
curlSetOpt(.opts = list(proxy = 'proxyIP:proxyPort',
                        proxyusername = "domain\\username", 
                        proxypassword = "password",
                        proxyauth="ntlm" 
                   ), curl = curl)
```